# Redirect my console output to my Tkinter text area widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a newbie on tkinter, my code can run but I need my text widget to display only the result variable in the callback() function not including the 'askopenfilename' method.

```
from Tkinter import *
    from tkFileDialog import *
    import os

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('900x700')
    path = StringVar()

    #browse pdf files
    def callback():
    f = askopenfilename(title='Open Files',initialdir='C:\Users\shantini\Desktop\PDF',
                        filetypes=[('Files of type:','*.PDF'),('Files of type:','*.pdf')])
    path.set(f)
    result = os.popen('pdfid.py'+' '+f).read()
    return result

#labelframe(text pdf output)
label=LabelFrame(root, text="PDF Analysis Output")
label.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
text = Text(label,bg='white')
text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
text.insert(INSERT,callback())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your formatting is off - you have a stray quotation mark somewhere

Comment: You seem to have some indentation issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable Text widget, you make it read-only, so you cant add text to it. So to add text, make it normal, or remove the state parameter. I changed your callback to reflect the comments:

```
def callback():
    f = askopenfilename(title='Open Files',initialdir='/tmp',
                        filetypes=[('Files of type:','*.PDF'),('Files of type:','*.pdf')])

    result = open(f).read() # I also changed this as I dont have `pdfid.py` to test the code
    text_area.insert(INSERT, result)
    print result
```

I slightly change the input files and folder, as I work in linux and cant use windows paths. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Marcin your right I need to remove the 'state=Disable' to be able to show the result. The only question now is how can I insert the result if its outside the function.